# How to write the Flash actionscript to makes this mouse action?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

A bit hard for me to describe the effect I need.
When I press the mouse and move it up,then release,it go to the next page.When I press the mouse and move it down,then release,it go to the previous page.
It's like swap desktop in smartphone.
I am not so familiar with Flash actionscript.
I have an idea to achieved this effect, which is when I press the mouse(MOUSE_DOWN), the Y-position of mouse was detected,and when I release the mouse(MOUSE_UP),another Y-position detected.
When the old Y > new Y , go to prevFrame(), and when the new Y > old Y, go to nextFrame().
Can anyone help me to write it with actionscript?I try but failed, cause I really can't understand the script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you are looking for, I recommend you to check also about [Touch](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html)/[Gesture](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/GestureEvent.html) events, also, check this library [Gestouch](https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch) (very powerful and well documented and with several [examples](https://github.com/fljot/GestouchExamples))

To help you to understand how to start understanding [ActionScript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/actionscript-3/info) and this logic in question, I wrote this simple example, only for educational purposes (not using touch/gesture events or proper code convention for naming and etc), you can apply your own logic and needs based in what you be able to extract from the example and related links that I'm mentioning in this answer.

*

```
// control for Y position when mouse down
var downY:Number = 0;
// control for Y position when mouse up
var upY:Number = 0;

// control for X position when mouse down
var downX:Number = 0;
// control for X position when mouse up
var upX:Number = 0;

// vertical or horizontal control (if true, we use the Y position, if false we use the X)
var verticalControl:Boolean = true;

// adding an event listeter to detect the mouse down state (you can apply the same for your own Object (sprite with image, or whatever you have in mind)
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, downHandler, false, 0, true);

function downHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, downHandler);
     stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, upHandler, false, 0, true);

     // collecting current Y and X position (mouse down state)
     downY = event.localY;
     downX = event.localX;
}

function upHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, upHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, downHandler, false, 0, true);

    // collecting current Y and X position (mouse up state)
    upY = event.localY;
    upX = event.localX;

    // checking if should use Y or X position
    (verticalControl) ? frameActionScope(upY, downY) : frameActionScope(upX, downX);
 }

 function frameActionScope(newValue:Number, oldValue:Number):void
 {
     // using your logic (When the old Y > new Y , go to prevFrame(), and when the new Y > old Y, go to nextFrame())
     (newValue >= oldValue) ? nextFrameScope() : prevFrameScope();
 }

 function nextFrameScope():void
 {
     trace('next frame');
 }

 function prevFrameScope():void
 {
     trace('previous frame');
 }
```

Hope you will be possible to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try to understand it and apply my logic. And thank you for tell me about Touch/Gesture events. This is the first time I come to stackoverflow, because I really can't find anyone that know actionscript to help me... I almost had a nervous breakdown for can't solve this problem...thankyou very very very much.

Answer (score 1):

In the solution posted by gPeart, you could also add some code to also capture the time stamp for the mouse press/release in adition to the co-ordinates. That way, you could calculate the length and direction and speed of the swipe. For very low speed,or very small distance, you could ignore the swipe; to make it feel like it only responds to genuine swipe.

Comment: Exactly, as I said, was just a simple example, possible to implement several controls to make it precise. Very well pointed!

Comment: Very good suggestion, I will try it if I could successfully understand the actionscript .